# How to share a image from getFilesDir() folder with SHARE INTENT?

Tags: android, share, android-contentprovider, android-sharing

i'm storing images that i download from internet here:  `getContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();`

I need to share some of these images with android share intent (ACTION_SEND), but for some reason, the intent can't access to these images.

How can it be done?

If it is not possible to access normally, ¿it is possible to access with a ContentProvider? ¿How?

thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html. check the docs

Answer (score -1):

Copy the file to someplace both apps can read, such as external storage.